# android emulator access server in local network

Tags: java, android, networking, android-emulator, emulation

i am having difficulties to have my android app running in the emulator to connect to servers in my local network.
i am getting a

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
```

but the servers are resolvable fine from the machine where the emulator is run.

thanks for any help on this topic!

Answer (score 11):

You have to use 10.0.2.2 to access local server.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest. This allows your application network access.

More can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions).